# TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str in os.system()

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write a python code which executes a C executable using the following line

```
os.system("./a.out \"%s\"" % payload)
```

where ./a.out is a C executable, and payload is a string (without spaces) given as command line argument. (The link is [this](http://codearcana.com/posts/2013/05/28/introduction-to-return-oriented-programming-rop.html). I am trying to follow example under section chaining functions)

 Now I have written another C code but it takes 3 command line arguments. So my string should be arg[1] + " " + arg[2] + " " + payloadString. 
(The c code is converting the arg[1] and arg[2] into integer to use it in its functions). Here is the snippet of my python code:

```
p = "10 "  #arg[1]
p += "10 " #arg[2]
p += "string without spaces which I need as payload" #arg[3]
os.system("./a.out \"%s\"" % p)
```

where ./a.out is executable of my C code which takes 3 command line arguments. When I run the python code I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "this_file.py", line XX, in <module>
os.system("./a.out \"%s\"" % p)
TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str
```

Can anyone help me?

P.S. I am new to python. Similar questions were there in stack overflow, but I am not sure how to use their answers to solve my problem.

Comment: I advise you to use the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) instead.

Comment: You don't need `os.system` to do that. Use `subprocess.call`: `subprocess.call(['./a.out', p])` no need of escaping anything. Also: the error message is about **null** characters, i.e. `\0`, not *whitespace* characters... are you sure that the `p` you are using is exactly the one you have shown us?

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact command line you're using? From what I've read, this error would happen if you have `\0` somewhere in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Put an `r` in the `os.system` call.

```
os.system(r"./a.out \"%s\"" % p)
```

Comment: The same error(TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str ) comes again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use call for this purpose. I guess it will do the work
You can provide the arguments in the list
Example:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["./a.out","10","10","string without spaces which I need as payload"])
```

here in your case it is equivalent to

```
call(["./a.out",arg[0],arg[1],arg[2]])
```

I think this should work

Comment: I ran this line call(["./a.out","10","10",p]) where p is my payload string, I got error : TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings.

Comment: you constructed your payload using the three arguments. I already passed your arguments as elements in the list. You need to pass the three arguments as elements in the list like I did. Or maybe there can be some type mismatch in your c program also. Please check it once.

Comment: while using "call", I modifed my string p not to include the arg[1] and arg[2]. I will check my C code to check for mismatches.

Comment: My payload string was using struct.pack() method. This was leading to the error message of "must contain only strings."